# How to filter a table by a specific array of strings and its order using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, json, api, filter

So i have been tinkering around with apis and i essentially created a table using vanilla javascript and a very lengthy set of sort commands that filter the table by string.

What i would like to achieve is set an object with strings in the order i want to filter by.
Taking the example of "rarity" in a video game. Using this filter, i would like to use this as a sorting function that filters the content in the table by the order that the filter defines.

Common > Uncommon > Rare > Epic > Legendary

I suppose you would need to give the function the key that you are looking for to compare between each "item" in the data set.

```
let filter = {
  "COMMON",
  "UNCOMMON",
  "RARE",
  "EPIC",
  "LEGENDARY
}
```

What would your approach be to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the Array like this. Hope this maybe helpful.

```
dataArray.sort((a, b) => filter.indexOf(a.dataKey) - filter.indexOf(b.dataKey))
```